# Is it has a limitation about size of apk, I built an apk on Unity. But It crashed when I install and open it. Here is my log. my Apk size over 2gb

Tags: unity-game-engine, apk, size

```
2021-06-02 13:39:14.547 1778-1954/? E/ScreenModeManager: updateGlobalModeId modeId 1 mCurrentModeId 1
2021-06-02 13:39:14.550 4172-4191/? E/oiface: client  not found, skipped
2021-06-02 13:39:14.552 1778-9509/? E/ScreenModeManager: updateGlobalModeId modeId 1 mCurrentModeId 1
2021-06-02 13:39:14.556 1778-9251/? E/ScreenModeManager: updateGlobalModeId modeId 1 mCurrentModeId 1
2021-06-02 13:39:14.559 3150-3150/? E/filemap: mmap(3710025728,2684) failed: Invalid argument
2021-06-02 13:39:14.559 3150-3150/? E/NewUnityProjec: Failed to mmap file 'resources.arsc' in APK '/data/app/com.DefaultCompany.NewUnityProject--LwelO8ZsoptnAlXFv36ig==/base.apk'
2021-06-02 13:39:14.559 3150-3150/? E/NewUnityProjec: Failed to open 'resources.arsc' in APK '/data/app/com.DefaultCompany.NewUnityProject--LwelO8ZsoptnAlXFv36ig==/base.apk'.
2021-06-02 13:39:14.559 3150-3150/? E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.DefaultCompany.NewUnityProject--LwelO8ZsoptnAlXFv36ig==/base.apk
2021-06-02 13:39:14.559 3150-3150/? E/ActivityThread: updateLocaleListFromAppContext context.getResources() is null ,return
2021-06-02 13:39:14.562 3150-3150/? E/filemap: mmap(3710025728,2684) failed: Invalid argument
2021-06-02 13:39:14.562 3150-3150/? E/NewUnityProjec: Failed to mmap file 'resources.arsc' in APK '/data/app/com.DefaultCompany.NewUnityProject--LwelO8ZsoptnAlXFv36ig==/base.apk'
2021-06-02 13:39:14.562 3150-3150/? E/NewUnityProjec: Failed to open 'resources.arsc' in APK '/data/app/com.DefaultCompany.NewUnityProject--LwelO8ZsoptnAlXFv36ig==/base.apk'.
2021-06-02 13:39:14.562 3150-3150/? E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.DefaultCompany.NewUnityProject--LwelO8ZsoptnAlXFv36ig==/base.apk
2021-06-02 13:39:14.563 3150-3150/? E/filemap: mmap(3710025728,2684) failed: Invalid argument
2021-06-02 13:39:14.563 3150-3150/? E/NewUnityProjec: Failed to mmap file 'resources.arsc' in APK '/data/app/com.DefaultCompany.NewUnityProject--LwelO8ZsoptnAlXFv36ig==/base.apk'
2021-06-02 13:39:14.563 3150-3150/? E/NewUnityProjec: Failed to open 'resources.arsc' in APK '/data/app/com.DefaultCompany.NewUnityProject--LwelO8ZsoptnAlXFv36ig==/base.apk'.
2021-06-02 13:39:14.563 3150-3150/? E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.DefaultCompany.NewUnityProject--LwelO8ZsoptnAlXFv36ig==/base.apk
2021-06-02 13:39:14.564 3150-3150/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.DefaultCompany.NewUnityProject, PID: 3150
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.AssetManager android.content.res.Resources.getAssets()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getAssets(LoadedApk.java:1247)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1336)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6882)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:235)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2068)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:238)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7890)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:983)
```

Comment: BTW, It works when I increase my asset below 2GB. But it crashed when it over 2GB. I wonder I was put to much things in StreamingAssets folder...

Comment: wow 2GB is extremely large! do you have an entire movie in your assets? :P

Comment: AFAIK, the Android platform does not support APKs that are larger than 2GB.

Comment: Thank you guys, I finally have an answer, Check the Build Settings - Player Settings - Other Settings - Configuration : change 'Scripting Backend' from 'Mono' to 'IL2CPP', and select 'Target Architectures - ARM64'.
Hope can help people who struggling on this issue. :)